# Google Cloud Build can't pull Container Registry images after 1 day

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We have CICD enabled, GCP Cloud Build has **all** the permissions (including Editor, Storage Admin and many many other permissions)

When we follow the steps for getting the image for the first time using instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase, cloud build works perfectly.

However, after some time (say 1 day), it starts giving error "unable to pull the image"

```
Step #0: latest: Pulling from <project name>/firebase
Step #0: 81fc19181915: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 828510924538: Pulling fs layer
...
Step #0: fe190282039f: Waiting
Step #0: error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
CANCELLED
ERROR: context canceled
ERROR: failed to pull because we ran out of retries.
```

If we upload the image again, it starts working again only for some time.

Note: We checked and the image is there in Container Registry, but still for some reason Google Cloud Build can't find it.

How can we fix this? Any suggestions on what we need to look at?

Uploading image every single time makes the whole CICD process redundant as we might as well deploy manually.

Thank you,

Comment: `error pulling image configuration: unknown blob` means image not found. I knowed you checked the image in container registry, but does the tag latest exist?

Comment: Yes, the tag 'latest' exists. What's interesting is that if we follow the same steps to upload a new version of the image, the Cloud Build continues as expected, but after some time it starts giving the same error and we have to reupload the image.

Also tried cleaning up all the images but issue persists.

Comment: Same problem.  Trying to convert an existing pipeline, after a while, base images lose layers in google's container registry.  Re-tagging the image and re-uploading works. I wonder if region-specific hostnames would be better (us-central1.gcr.io instead of us.gcr.io)

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue - after pulling images successfully for a period I would start getting the error "unable to pull the image".  Permissions were not the issue.

I found my problem.  Google GCP Container Registry stores the Docker artefacts in Google GCP Storage in artifacts.<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com.  I set 2 week expiry times on all my Cloud Storage locations to save money.  Therefore whenever a Docker artefact was deleted in Cloud Storage all the related Docker images in GCP Container Registry would report an unknown blob when trying to download the deleted slice and the image download would fail.  Maybe Google could have explained the link to Cloud Storage better but I suppose should not have set expiry times on storage locations for which I didn't know the exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the Cloud Build only works for one day,  you need to re-upload the image to make sure it is working. I think the issue may be caused by the cloud build configuration, maybe be the trigger or tags. Since it is not appropriate to provide your cloud build configuration file here. I recommend you to open a support ticket in the Cloud Console. You can refer to this [link](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/1041916?hl=en#) to get the instruction of how to File a support case.

Comment: Thank you, but the link you provided is only for GSuite issues. For any GCP issues, the support is only valid for customers paying money for the "support" itself. I went to each and every sub link in the link you provided, but there's absolutely no way to raise an issue to GCP team for Container Registry issue that we are facing.

If there's something I missed, please do advise!

Comment: You can find Free trial support in the [CCP support hub](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-1).
 And provide your cloud build configuration file there. GCP support team will address the specific issue.